# Detecting windows version

Tags: jquery, windows, browser

I seem to be having a nightmare with jQuery and getting it to working the same in older IE. 
This I can try and test but then I have also noticed that transitions and mainly timing runs differently in different versions of windows. Mainly this is IE8. In XP it runs differently than in vista. 
I was wondering if there is any way for Javascript or jQuery to detect what version of windows if being run by the user like when detecting browser version. This way can switch over to a different JS file that has been amended for it.

Comment: Just a tid bit of info regarding the js detection of users OS. The navigator object supplies a userAgent property. You read about it here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent

Comment: Cheers that should help. Would anyone have any idea of what the(window.navigator.userAgent) would be if in windows XP?

Comment: Otherwise it should be "Windows NT 5.1"
And some more info on those...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#PltToken

http://user-agents.my-addr.com/user_agent_request/user_agent_examples-and-user_agent_types.php

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]—>

<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css">
<![endif]—>
```

Older versions of IE are a pain and don’t confirm to W3 standards.  There is a line you can use to help IE8 work in a more standard way:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

IE7 and IE6 are hopeless and as a developer I no longer support them.

In addition you can use server side languages to further enhance your customization but your question was about HTML/jQuery so I’ll leave it at that.

Comment: Thats great if its just browser issue but some transitions I have done work differently if ie8 is used by Windows XP and if ie8 is being used by Vista or 7. Its mainly with timing of callbacks. They either come in too early or way too late.

Comment: Forget I asked about PHP..  check this for additional info: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm  You can access the DOM to figure out what version of the OS someone is running.

Comment: Ok I shall try the meta tag. Cheers and let you know it if works. I Mostly not put an update message on anything that is lower than 9 but still lots of clients have old explorer installed and older window systems such as XP.

Comment: I tried this but no result. This is the link to the current animation. http://www.gbutlercreative.co.uk/londonmain/frame.html when I run it in ie 7 the callback functions which are the iframe moving comes in too fast but when I run it in ie8 its fine. When I run it in ie8 but in windows XP. The Iframe movement timing takes ages to kick in. Surely a time out should always happen straight after the function applied.